# Removing objects from memory in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am new to c++ but from what I understood you need to delete objects from memory when you are done with them.

Having a class called myClass. If I create a new instance and call some of its functionalities. Like so:

```
MyClass p;
p.funcCall(12);
p.anOtherFuncCall(4);
```

How am I supposed to free the memory occupied by p again? I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/delete-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019) Microsoft article. But if I change it to:

```
MyClass* p = new MyClass
... call fucntions
delete p;
```

I can no longer call my functions like `p.funcCall(12)`.

If I understood memory management in c++ incorrectly I would love to hear that as well.

Comment: contrary to common belief memory is managed automatically in c++ (unless you explicitly ask for something else)

Comment: I would recommend obtaining one of [these books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you want to learn C++. You won't get far by piecing your knowledge together from documentation articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code

```
MyClass p;
p.funcCall(12);
p.anOtherFuncCall(4);
```

You don't have to manually delete `p`. It is automatically invalidated once it goes out of scope. This is explained in greater detail [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). You can just leave it this way.

```
MyClass* p = new MyClass
... call fucntions
delete p;
```

You can also do it that way if you want. Since `p` is not a `MyClass` anymore but a pointer to one, the syntax is different, though. You have to write it like this instead:

```
p->funcCall(12);
```

Comment: As I said being completely new to c++ and memory management in it. Does the first not result in allocated memory that is not deallocated until the program finishes?

Comment: In the first one, the memory is on the stack and will be invalidated like any other stack variable. Just like how for instance `int a;` would become invalid after the block it was declared in.

Answer (score 0):

So basically C++ won't manage memory for you, at least it's not a default feature of the language. That certainly doesn't mean that you need to store every object as a pointer and free it manually though. In your case the object is initialized in the local [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) which means it will get destroyed as soon as it leaves that scope. This is because you constructed it as a value, if you had allocated memory yourself for it (i.e global scope) then you're responsible for freeing said memory. There's another option for pointers as well though, using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) will automate the cleanup of objects in the global scope.